# Installing AMD graphics drivers & running Starcraft2

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I installed Ubuntu 16.04, fully aware that it was never going to be able to run Starcraft 2 as well as Windows, but nevertheless I held out hope that it would still perform well, since it's not a very graphically intensive game.

- I installed WINE and SC2 and played a few levels using the default Ubuntu graphics driver. The game only ran at ~45FPS on low graphic settings, which was reduced ~12FPS on medium and high.
- I believe, however, that my computer is capable of doing better, and that this is just a driver issue.
- So, I installed `AMDGPU-pro` driver. Then it said I needed to re-login for the changes to take affect. When I tried to do this, I just ran into the well known "login loop" issue, and it persisted even after a restart.
- Just for the heck of it, I installed SC2 on my 2 year old MacBook Air, and it was able to achieve 140FPS on low and 25FPS on high, which again leads me to believe it should run better on my desktop.

---

### So, in the end then, two questions:

1. How can I properly load a better driver for my GPU?
2. Is there a better way to run Starcraft 2 than running it in WINE?

---

Here are my specs:

```
MoBo: Gigabyte F2A68HM-H
CPU: AMD A10 7860k APU
RAM: 8GB
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Good for you for taking your first step into the world of free and open source software! Just FYI, I've edited your question, removing irrelevant information, and also improving the formatting and overall quality.

Comment: Have you tried enabling CSMT [as detailed here](https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/CSMT)?

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev.  Thanks for editing my post.  I was worried that I wasn't as concise as I should have been.

Comment: Did you see my previous comment about CSMT?