# Python: Anaconda path only added on demand

Tags: command-line, python, anaconda

The situation is the following:

- So far I have only used pip to install any package I needed or also
  apt-get sometimes. I have installed things like tensorflow with gpu
  support and things like that. At least at the time I installed this I
  was not aware of an easy way to install tensorflow in anaconda with
  gpu support, so I decided to just install it on the regular/standard
  python.
- Now and for the future I intend to use anaconda. But I do not want to
  lose easy access to my old python libraries, but also not have to
  reinstall everything in anaconda.
- Now I installed anaconda. But when I now open Jupyter notebook I am
  in the conda python, as I have added the conda path.

**Is there maybe an easy way to achieve the following: When I open a terminal, all I need to do is type a quick command that will only then add the anaconda path?**

This is to achieve that when I just open the terminal and type jupyter notebook, my go to python distribution will be the distribution where I installed tensorflow and stuff. And then I can easily use the command to enter the anaconda environments.

The following line in the .bashrc will add the conda path:

```
$ export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

**So my question probably boils down to this: Is there a way to link this with some sort of command?** So that the following would happen if I open a terminal:

```
jupyter notebook
```

--> jupyter notebook starts, NOT using anaconda. But when I do:

```
command_that_adds_the_anaconda_path
jupyter notebook
```

--> jupyter notebook starts, using anaconda

Big thanks in advance. I am rather new to shell stuff. Any link to how to create such a command will be much appreciated. I looked for it, maybe using the wrong words, but haven't found exactly this.

Comment: Your question is kind of a wall of text. Do you think you could add some formatting to make it easier to read? See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/911604/518562) for an example of good formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH`. When run in a terminal session (as opposed to from `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`), it will only affect that session and its child processes.